# Python package not available from installed Python script in Windows with Anaconda

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, setup.py

I wrote a package 'myname' which is structured as follows

```
/myname
__init__.py
----/raster/
    ----/__init__.py
    ----/raster1.py
    ----/raster2.py
----/config/
    ----/__init__.py
    ----/config.py
----/misc/
    ----/__init__.py
    ----/misc.py
----/bin/
    ----/myname.py
```

where `myname.py` is a command-line script which makes use of all the sub-packages of package `myname`.

The minimal version of my `setup.py` is as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
    name = 'myname',
    packages=['myname','myname.config','myname.misc','myname.raster'],
    scripts = ['myname/bin/myname.py'],
)
```

The package is installed with `python setup.py install` and works out of the box in Linux.
On Windows with Anaconda the script is unable to find the packages. At some point of the script I have written

```
from myname.config import blabla
```

and I get `ImportError: no module named config`

while if I time the same into the python interpreter I get the import done.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: it appears that `in Windows you cannot give the script the same name of the package`.